# Case insensitive Lambda Expression with Contains

Tags: c#, contains, case-insensitive, lambda, dynamic-linq

I have a the following code:

```
public override IList<IEntity> GetByEmail(IList<string> emailAddresses)
    {


        //build lambda expression
        var result = All.Where(BuildEmailFilterExpression<T, string>(
            propertyInfo.Name, x => emailAddresses.Contains(x)));

        return result.Cast<IEntity>().ToList();
    }

    private static Func<T, bool> BuildEmailFilterExpression<TSource, TProp>(
        string propertyName, Expression<Func<TProp, bool>> predicate)
    {
        ParameterExpression paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource));
        MemberExpression propExpr = Expression.Property(paramExpr, propertyName);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Invoke(predicate, propExpr), 
            paramExpr).Compile();
    }
```

The All function returns entities in ths case Person the property Email needs to be case insensitive.
How can I make this expression case insensitive, ToUpper or ToLower without using IndexOf.

Comment: Add a language tag (is C#, isn't?)

Comment: Yes C# tag added thnx.

Comment: Can't you just change `x => emailAddresses.Contains(x)` to `x => emailAddresses.Contains(x, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)`?

Comment: Thanx Matthew that does the trick, how can I mark your comment as the Answer